# Appropriate use of inline tag edits

Tags: discussion, tags

As a new 10K+ user, I was reading the descriptions for all the new powers I have. The last one (inline tag edits) sounded like a really cool feature. Specifically, it sounded very useful for helping to burninate tags.

That left me with a concern though. Normally, I would reject a tag-only edit as too minor (especially if there are other problems with the post). This feature would seem to encourage tag-only edits from high-rep users. Of course we don't get any reputation for them, but it makes me wonder.

**What is the appropriate use of this feature?**

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question should go in that power's help section on the aforementioned page?

Comment: Just with the non-need for ordinary edits to be reviewd, to edit minor things like typos, I think this is exactly the point for why high-rep is needed: we dont want to clog review queues with minor crap, but if it needs to be done, it is nice to have people that can do it. Sometimes it is the only thing that is "wrong" with a post, so why not have someone do it? Let someone do it who is trusted, so not all the review queue resources are consumed.

Comment: I've got an auto-edit script to burn tags using this functionality.  I'll open 30 questions from the tag page at once (request throttling on the server).  I can rip fifty questions of crap tags in under two minutes.  If that's abuse, I don't wanna be kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the appropriate use of this feature?

The appropriate use of this feature is to edit the tags on a question, either adding tags that would be appropriate or removing those that are not. This seems like a trick question to me.

> Normally, I would reject a tag-only edit as too minor (especially if there are other problems with the post).

You cannot reject an edit by a user with full editing privileges as "too minor". The reason why "too minor" edits are a problem is because of the cost of reviewing suggested edits. It takes at least three experienced users to take their attention away from the normal business of the site, monitor the review queue, read the suggested edit, and evaluate it. Such is not a problem for edits that actually contribute something useful, but we want to discourage the process from being abused. Conversely, edits from users with 3k+ reputation do not go into the review queue and are therefore far less costly.

Granted, there is still no reason to avoid fixing obvious problems with a post when you're editing its tags. You don't use the inline tag editor in these cases. That doesn't mean it not useful. I use it frequently.

> This feature would seem to encourage tag-only edits from high-rep users.

Yup. So?

Tags are important. They're how we categorize and find questions. If a question is poorly tagged, that's a situation that needs to be remedied. And now you have a quick, convenient way to do so. The whole point of reputation is a measure of trust. If you've earned the privileges, then we feel like we can trust you to use them appropriately.

> Specifically, it sounded very useful for helping to burninate tags.

Meh. I've grown weary of the recent obsession with tag burnination. Sure, there are bad tags, and they need to be removed. But judging by some of the recent "tag burnination" discussions, I've begun to feel that there are far more productive ways to spend time improving the site. The focus needs to be on making concrete improvements, not just cleaning out tags that don't tickle your fancy or upset your aesthetic sensibilities. And I say this as a person with strong obsessive-compulsive tendencies.

Anyway, rant over; that wasn't really the point of your question. Yes, this feature might be useful when burninating tags, but it is also useful in plenty of other one-off situations, like retagging a new question with minimal fuss. New users often don't understand our tagging system, so you see *many* new questions that are tagged very poorly. This gives you an easy way of fixing the problem.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize that the primary reason to reject "too minor" edits was the review queue. Obviously fixing the whole post is the best scenario, but I am much more comfortable with this feature now. The part you thought was "trick" wasn't intended to be :) I was just confused as to the nature of a feature who, by design, encourages and allows very small edits. I wasn't sure if I was missing something important.