# Two often confused tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

**Short background:** 
[depth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search) tag is used for *[depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)* related questions:

> Depth-first search (DFS) is an algorithm for traversing or searching a
>   tree, tree structure, or graph.

*Depth-first search* is very often referred to as DFS.

Unfortunately, there is another tag called [dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs):

> DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft

**The problem:** 
Those two tags are often confused. I see [dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) used instead of [depth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search) very often.

**What I did:**

- I *edited* tons of past questions tags (probably well over 100) and keep doing so
- Changed [DFS] tag description to include: Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. ***Not*** **to be confused** with [depth-first-search].

**My question:**

Clearly the change of description is not enough.
 
What can be done to further reduce confusing  [depth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search) with [dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs)?

Comment: Perhaps the DFS tag can be renamed to `microsoft-dfs` or `microsoft-distributed-file-system`. I think it's more consistent to alias `dfs` to `depth-first-search` since [`bfs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs) is an alias for Breadth First Search.

Comment: @VLAZ Renaming [DFS] as you suggest can certainly solve the problem.

Comment: For fun, I checked if BFS is also a file system somewhere and turns out it is the [Be File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be_File_System). We don't have a tag for it but I did find the [tag:boost-filesystem] tag. In theory, that can also be abbreviated to BFS. Not sure if it is done so on practice. At any rate, to me BFS/DFS refer to the search strategies. I don't know how popular Microsoft DFS is and whether it requires to take over the DFS tag.

Comment: Related: *[Tag only edits should not bump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310787)* and *[Is it appropriate to only edit tags when a post has more issues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285402)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've renamed the tag [dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) to [microsoft-distributed-file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-distributed-file-system) to disambiguate it from both depth-first search and from the generic [distributed-filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-filesystem) tag. I also updated the tag wiki excerpt.

**Action Item:** The [microsoft-distributed-file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-distributed-file-system) needs some cleanup love, both to close off-topic questions about file systems (i.e., those that do not relate to programming), and to retag questions that are about depth-first searches.

With this, the tag [dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) was removed from the system. I have now added [dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) as a synonym of [depth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search), keeping the latter as the "master" tag for clarity. Note that this matches what is done with breadth-first search ([breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search) ← [bfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs)).

If we need to deal with other "BFS" acronyms, like the Be File System, then a descriptive tag can be created for those (e.g., [be-file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/be-file-system)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You may want to include Microsoft or MS in the tag to make it clear and distinct from other [distributed-filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-filesystem)

Comment: @c0der Ack. Did not notice that in my search. Okay, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. It is going to save me some editing time (0:

Comment: We can hope it will. Not everyone notices that the system automatically replaces their typed tags with a synonym whose name implies something completely different...

Comment: Can you help with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409256/duplicate-tags-for-path-finding-pathfinder-path-finding-and-pathing-qui) related issue ?